# How to pass html attribute to Python script?

Tags: python, html, web

I have a python script which validates ID no. I have html form too which I want to pass string of one field to python script and return answer. 
My script look like:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys, string, re

def checkID():
    error=False
    if len(sys.argv) <> 2:
        print "Error: Missing argument (Usage: id ID_Number\n"
    else:
        idNumber=sys.argv[1]
        for oneDigit in idNumber:
            if not(oneDigit in string.digits):
                error=True
                break
        if error:
            print "Error: Illegal ID number: '%s'\n" % idNumber
        else:
            if len(idNumber) > 9:
                error=True
                print "Error: ID number too long: '%s'\n" % idNumber

    return error


badNumber = checkID(sys.argv[1])
newID = ''
if not badNumber:
    if len(sys.argv[1]) < 9:
        missingDigits = 9 - len(sys.argv[1])
        while missingDigits > 0:
            newID=newID+'0'
            missingDigits = missingDigits - 1
        newID = newID + sys.argv[1]
    else:
        newID = sys.argv[1]

theSum = 0
indexRange=[0,2,4,6]
for i in indexRange:
    digit = newID[i]
    num= int(digit)
    theSum = theSum + num
    num= int(newID[i+1]) * 2
    if num > 9:
        num1 = num / 10
        num2 = num % 10
        num = num1 + num2
    theSum = theSum + num
theSum = theSum + int(newID[8])
lastDigit = theSum % 10
if lastDigit <> 0:
    print '\nID number: "%s" is wrong\n' % str(newID)
else:
    print '\nID number: "%s" is valid\n' % str(newID)
```

So the Python will check the string passes from html and validate it.
How can I do it?

Comment: Do you already have a web server configured to run Python code? If not, is your web site hosted somewhere under your control and which server are you running? There are many improvements that could be made to this script such as using regular expressions for validation and list comprehensions to simplify the checksum processing.

Comment: Did you search/tried using python-cgi ?